# Custom Delegate cannot find declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm creating a shopping list app, and trying to implement a custom delegate when editing an item.  When creating the `@protocol` at the bottom of the header file, when trying to declare a property of that protocol in the `@interface` section I'm getting an error of: `Cannot find protocol declaration for GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate`

This is what my header file looks like.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GEMItem.h"

@interface GEMEditItemViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property GEMItem *item;
@property (weak) id<GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)controller:(GEMEditItemViewController *)controller didUpdateItem:(GEMItem *)item;
@end // End of delegate protocol
```

Alternatively in a separate instance when declaring the `protocol` above the `interface` I cannot access the view controller to pass as a parameter for that declaration method.

That header file looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GEMItemManager.h"

@protocol GEMAddItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
/*
// Tried to add the controller (controller:(GEMAddItemviewController *)controller) as first paramiter, but was getting and errror, so I have omitted it for the time being
- (void)controller:(GEMAddItemViewController *)controller didSaveItemWithName:(NSString *)name andQuantity:(float)quantity andPrice:(float)price andCategory:(NSString *)category andNotes:(NSString *)notes;
*/

- (void)didSaveItemWithName:(NSString *)name andQuantity:(float)quantity andPrice:(float)price andCategory:(NSString *)category andNotes:(NSString *)notes;

@end

@interface GEMAddItemViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak) id<GEMAddItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property NSArray *categories;

@end
```

Any thoughts on how to correct this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this also

```
@protocol GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate;
@interface GEMEditItemViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property GEMItem *item;
@property (weak) id<GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)controller:(GEMEditItemViewController *)controller didUpdateItem:(GEMItem *)item;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
@class GEMEditItemViewController; // forward declaration of class

@protocol GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)controller:(GEMEditItemViewController *)controller didUpdateItem:(GEMItem *)item;
@end // End of delegate protocol

@interface GEMEditItemViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property GEMItem *item;
@property (weak) id<GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

BTW - you should move the two picker view protocols from the header file to a class extension in the .m file. The world doesn't need to know this implementation detail.

Comment: When I move it to the top I then get an error of `Expected a type` for `(GEMAddItemViewController *)`

Comment: Thanks, I moved the picker view protocols as well

Answer (score 0):

Your header file should looks like this:

```
@class GEMEditItemViewController;
@class GEMItem;

@protocol GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)controller:(GEMEditItemViewController *)controller didUpdateItem:(GEMItem *)item;
@end // End of delegate protocol

@interface GEMEditItemViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property GEMItem *item;
@property (weak) id<GEMEditItemViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

You should not use direct import in your header file. `@class` directive is used to prevent cycle dependencies. In your case GEMItem import should be in your meta file.